# Circuit diagram of LiFePo4 charger with additional battery protection

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, protection, circuit-protection, lifepo4

I want to design a small circuit board that includes a charge controller for a LiFePo4 battery and a protection circuit for the device behind it.

I use a vertical USB-C port for 5V Power-Input Texas Instruments **BQ25170** ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25170.pdf?ts=1657669528811&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ25170)) as a charge controller and a **HY2112** ([Datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1139782/HYCON/HY2112.html)) and a **FS8205A MOSFET** ([Datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1132762/FORTUNE/FS8205A.html)) for the protection circuit.

This is my first time designing a board so I'm not sure if the circuit is right. I hope that someone can take a look at it and tell me directly what I did wrong and what I did right.

[image: Circuit diagram charge controller and battery protection]

Comment: For starters you will need pulldown resistors in order to get 5V from the USB-C device on the other end of the cable. You should also connect all the GND and VBUS pins of the connector together.

Comment: I also don't see any ground connection between the USB side and the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why should I connect all the GND and VBUS pins of the connector together?

The GND connection goes from the USB port to the capacitor C1, into the GND pin of the BQ25170 and into the resistor R3 just before the VSET pin. The GND connection for the rest of the circuitry continues from the battery.

Comment: Because the USB standard mandates it, and it improves the current-carrying capability of the connector and cable. Without the GND connection from the left your battery won't charge.

Comment: But GND and VBUS together is a short circuit - or not?

Comment: No, you should connect all the GND pins together and all the VBUS pins together.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you mean. Thanks for your reply. Do you think the rest looks good?

Comment: No idea. How is the load connected and how will it be powered during charging?